# Python Basics: How can i set two function parameters in equations?

Tags: python, function

I have a basic question on python functions and parameters

Given this function:

```
def findArticleWithAttr(tableattrib, user_url_input):
    articles = Something.objects.filter(tableattrib=user_url_input)
```

I call the function with:

```
findArticleWithAttr(attribute1, userinput1)
```

tableattrib is not set by findArticleWithAttr attribute1 and just takes the latter (userinput1) parameter and replaces it.

How can i make python set both parameters in the equation?

Comment: Not sure of what are you trying here, but this `Something.objects.filter(tableattrib=user_url_input)` doesn't seem correct. What you're doing in there is passing `user_url_input` to an argument called `tableattrib` for the method `.filter`. Not sure, but I think that's not what you want... Also, what's this? Django?

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes: He's trying to allow the attribute by which to filter to be specified as an argument to `findArticleWithAttr`. Obviously this doesn't work, as `tableattrib` is treated as a keyword identifier rather than a variable identifier in this syntax.

Comment: Hi...yes you are right... its django...what i want is to define the parameter and attribute from an outside function...thanks for your comment

Comment: thanks @ Will that's what i want ;-P is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `**` [double-splat operator](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/):

```
def findArticleWithAttr(tableattrib, user_url_input):
    articles = Something.objects.filter(**{tableattrib : user_url_input})
```

---

Basically, the `**` operator makes

```
func(**{'foo' : 'bar'})
```

equivalent to

```
func(foo = 'bar')
```

It allows you to call a function with arbitrary keyword arguments.

Comment: For more information about this method of passing parameters, look at "unpacking" or this relevant SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334655/passing-a-dictionary-to-a-function-in-python-as-keyword-parameters