# Python peewee update keyword as variable

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

Is it possible, in Python using peewee + MySQL database, to use some variable as keyword in update function?

For example:

```
what = raw_input('What you want to change? name, surname, email ')
value = raw_input('What is the value?')

update = Users.update(what=value).where(Users.id == some_user_id)
update.execute()
```

If we have table like this:

```
class Users(BaseModel):
    email = CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    name = CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    surname = CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'users'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an unpacked [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) as a keyword argument, like so:

```
update = Users.update(**{what: value}).where(Users.id == some_user_id)
```

Example of how it works:

```
>>>def foo(a=2):
...    print a
...
>>>foo(**{'a': 3})
3
>>>b = 'a'
>>>foo(**{b: 4})
4
>>>foo(**{'c': 5})
TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'
>>>foo({'a': 6})
{'a': 6}
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334655/passing-a-dictionary-to-a-function-in-python-as-keyword-parameters)