# Passing kwargs to a function invokes TypeError

Tags: python, function, dictionary, parameters

I was writing a wrapper method when the error occurred. I've managed to simplify the problem to the following piece of code:

```
def func1(data, **kwargs):
    func2(data, kwargs)

def func2(data, **kwargs):
    print(data)
```

The `TypeError: func2() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` appears when running `func1`.

Regardless of what named arguments I put into the function call, the error occurs. However, if I don't pass `kwargs` to `func2`, everything runs smoothly.

Most of the information I found about the error message dealt with class methods not calling `self`, which is not the case.

Comment: While writing and proof-reading the question, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/334655/2651145) question, which deals with similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, when calling `func2(data, kwargs)` from within `func1` we are suppling `func2` with two arguments, `data` and `kwargs`, a dictionary.

Even if the dictionary is empty, it is still a single item, which is recognized as another argument (and not as the sequence of named arguments `func1` was called), hence the error message.

Since `func2` expects to be called in the following manner:

```
func2(data, arg1='alpha', arg2='beta', arg3=... )
```

[Unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the dictionary is needed. `func1` should therefore be:

```
def func1(data, **kwargs):
    func2(data, **kwargs)
```

Note the `**` on the `func2` call, this makes it so that the dictionary is unpacked and resemble what `func2` expects to be called.