# Querying MYSQL with Django framework in HTML

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am building a site using Django framework with google api + MYSql. Currently I display all data entries' latitude and longitude from my dB onto a heatmap layer.

I need to be able to filter my data to refine what I am displaying. e.g - I would like to filter **HazardInside.title** by types such as "Slip" and "trip".

This filter will need to be able to filter by many other requirements simultaneously such as date and weather conditions. e.g title="Slip" + weather="Wet" + between dates of (dd/mm/yy - dd/mm/yy)

My current problem is successfully creating a view that requests new data from my dB and parses it to my HTML page.

## models.py

```
class HazardInside(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    incident_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    lat = models.FloatField(max_length=25, default=0.00000)
    lng = models.FloatField(max_length=25, default=0.00000)
    room_number = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    floor = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class InjuryInside(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    incident_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    lat = models.FloatField(max_length=25, default=0.00000)
    lng = models.FloatField(max_length=25, default=0.00000)
    room_number = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    floor = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from qutheatmap.models import Markers, HazardInside, InjuryInside
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def home(request):
    marker = Markers.objects.all()
    hazardinsides = HazardInside.objects.all()
    injuryinsides = InjuryInside.objects.all()

    mapdata = {
        'markers': marker,
        'hazardinsides': hazardinsides,
        'injuryinsides': injuryinsides
    }

    return render(request, 'heatmap/map.html', mapdata)

def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('type')
    try:
        query = char(query)
    except ValueError:
        query = None
        hazardinsides = None
    if query:
        hazardinsides = HazardInside.objects.get(title=query)
    context = RequestContext(request)

    mapdata = {
        'markers': marker,
        'hazardinsides': hazardinsides,
        'injuryinsides': injuryinsides
    }

    return render_to_response('heatmap/map.html', {"hazardinsides": hazardinsides,}, context_instance=context)
```

## within my html

```
<form method="get" action="http://localhost:8000/qutheatmap/">
  Search:<input type="text" name="type" id="id_q" value="{{ query }}"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

I have tried a few different methods with my limited Django knowledge to no avail such as:

1. [Django form to query database (models)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225601/django-form-to-query-database-models)
2. [Querying a django DB with model forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462413/querying-a-django-db-with-model-forms)

EDIT:

## URLs

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^$', views.search),
]
```

## URLs config

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from qutheatmap import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'qutheatmap/', include('qutheatmap.urls')),
]
```

Comment: You need to show what you tried and failed.

Comment: Separately, there doesn't seem to be a need for two models here; they have exactly the same fields. It would be better to have a single model - Incident, Report, or whatever - with a `type` field.

Comment: updated - this is what I currently have, just trying to search for the title as a temporary input field. - in regards to the two models. I have plans to merge the two, currently I have two tables within MySql.

Comment: And what happens with this code (apart from an error that `char` is not defined)?

Comment: the page reloads with "/?type=Slip+Hazard" appended to the url and nothing else that I can see. If char should throw an error does that mean query isnt getting set correctly then?

Comment: What do your URLs look like? Is "/qutheatmap" mapped to the search view?

Comment: I had forgotten to add that, I just added it in.

Comment: But you have two identical patterns. You can't do that. Django will always call the first match, so the search view will never be called.

Comment: so would I need to change the regular expression to match the "/?" for it to call that view

Comment: No, you need to pick a completely separate URL - for example "search" - and point your form action to that. (As another aside, don't include the full domain there as it won't work once you've deployed; just do `action="/qutheatmap/search/"` or whatever.)

Comment: Doesn't that mean creating a new page also? I'd like to remain on the single page