# How to pass in dynamic class method key value parameters in python

Tags: python

i could not find seemingly similarly already posted in stack so here goes a short example:

```
# Current Code
dbCon = pyodbc.connect(sCon, autocommit=True)

# Future/Desired pseudo code
vAutocommit = {'autocommit': True}
dbCon = pyodbc.connect(sCon, vAutocommit)
```

I'm sure i'm missing a simple python concept so please forgive to being newer to this language.  Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a dictionary to a function as keyword parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334655/passing-a-dictionary-to-a-function-as-keyword-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the dictionary and unpack it as a `kwarg`:

```
# Current Code
dbCon = pyodbc.connect(sCon, autocommit=True)

# Future/Desired pseudo code
vAutocommit = {'autocommit': True}
dbCon = pyodbc.connect(sCon, **vAutocommit) <<< the ** unpacks the
                                                dictionary's key/value
                                                pairs as arguments.
```

Comment: Thank you!  appreciate the simplicity.