# Dynamically passing the object properties as params of a method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in a context where I have a dynamic objects as parameters and different classes to instantiate. I already managed how to load the classes into a dictionary, so I can instantiate any class passed as a string through command line, but I didn't figure it out how to "unpack" any object into parameters. E.g. the constructor of my Vectorizer class receives the following arguments:

```
Vectorizer(encoding=encoding, use_idf=True, norm='l2')
```

So, anytime the user indicates that this class must be instantiated, I also receive an object with the following example properties:

```
params = { "encoding":"utf8", "use_idf"=True, "norm"="l2"}
```

But I can not instantiate the Vectorizer like this:

```
Vectorizer(params)
```

I know a possible solution is doing refactoring in all existing classes and receiving a unique param containing all the propieries, but I would really like to avoid that, so I can keep the current descriptive constructors.

So, any idea about how to pass the params object as the required arguments?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: See [Passing a dictionary to a function as keyword parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334655/passing-a-dictionary-to-a-function-as-keyword-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
Vectorizer(**params)
```

This is called *dictionary unpacking* and is [described in the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays).

Comment: I swear you I tried before asking and didn't work in the console. But I tried again, this time on the script, and it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: And thanks for indicating the concept and the docs!! I really wanted to know how to call it