# Getting invalid argument error for print function

Tags: python, dictionary

I am getting invalid argument error while trying to print dictionary values.

```
dict={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
print(*dict)
print(**dict)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-92f0ed7852d8> in <module>
      1 dict={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
      2 print(*dict)
----> 3 print(**dict)

TypeError: 'a' is an invalid keyword argument for print()
```

Comment: Why are you using `print(**dict)` and not just `print(dict)`? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: That's not how you print dictionary values. Use `print(*d.values())` instead. Also, do not name your variables same as python built-ins. `dict` is a bad variable name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a dictionary to a function as keyword parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334655/passing-a-dictionary-to-a-function-as-keyword-parameters)

Comment: Thank you Sayandip Dutta for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The **dict is used to "Unpacks the contents of a dictionary into the function call, see the reference here:[**Dictionary](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html)

```
def add (a=0, b=0, c= 0):
   return a + b + c
dict={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
print(*dict)
unpacking = add(**dict)
print(unpacking)
```

The printed unpacking value will be equal to 6.

You can use dict.values() to get the values of the dictionary. E.g. `print (dict.values())` will return

```
dict_values([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Is there any possible to print just values without open and close braces and parantheis?like it should just print 1,2,3

Comment: @JagadeeshJaga, Sanandip has already answered. Use `print (*dict.values())` will print only the list values.