# Send unknown parameters to a function not as dictionary

Tags: python

Sorry if this is dumb.
I am looking for a **clean** way to do this :

```
addQuery(slop=33,win=2) //here we could have any new arg like xyz="arg"

def addQuery(unknown_arg):
    print(unknown_arg.slop, unknown_arg.win) //will check and print only if slop/win exist in arg list
```

I ***could*** send `dic` like : `addQuery({slop:33,win:2})`
and access with `dic["slop"]` which is ugly.

I want a `tuple` like solution. `(a=1,b=2)`. I can't list all possible arguments(>20).
The argument to this function could be different each call.

Comment: **kwargs - explained here: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html - I would say - duplicate....

Comment: thanks, this is nice but still not amazing because I still need to access with kwargs['slop'], not dot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a dictionary to a function as keyword parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334655/passing-a-dictionary-to-a-function-as-keyword-parameters)

Comment: @baltiturg please elaborate why do you need that? Besides - you can use comprehension to deal with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution to the issue you are facing involves 2 key steps.

- accepting variable amount of keyword arguments (we will use [`**kwargs`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html) here)
- making dictionary keys accessible as attributes ( [`attrdict`](https://pypi.org/project/attrdict/))

Here is a sample snippet that demonstrates how it can be achieved:

```py
from attrdict import AttrDict # 'pip install attrdict' first

def addQuery(**kwargs):  # helps with step #1
    unknown_arg = AttrDict(kwargs) # make the arguments accessible as attributes (like 'unknown_args.arg' instead of 'unknown_args['arg'])
    print(unknown_arg.slop, unknown_arg.win) # will check and print only if slop/win exist in arg list

addQuery(slop=33,win=2)
```

Comment: Did you mean to link to [attrdict](https://pypi.org/project/attrdict/)? That's not built-in... A built-in replacement could be [`argparse.Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace)

Comment: @Tomerikoo yeah made a typo.. fixed

Answer (score -1):

Assuming "tuple-like solution" means you want a tuple-like set of parameters in the function, you could use `**kwargs` to get a dictionary of all implicit values passed and then convert that to a list:

```py
func(explicit_arg, **kwargs):
    keys = ['expected', 'caller', 'keywords'] # this is a list of all possible keywords you expect
    params = [kwargs[k] if k in kwargs.keys() else None for k in keys]
```

Then you can access your implicit parameters by position in `params` and they'll be `None` if not passed.