# How to use square brackets as part of a variable name in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

I am trying to use pandas.assign function. The function adds another column into an existing column.

For example

```
DataFrame1 = DataFrame1.assign(NewColName=[1,2,3,4])
```

Adds a new column named `"NewColName"`. However, my ideal column name would be `"Weight [kg]"`, and when I try to use `"[ ]"` the function ceases to work. I have tried applying `%'s` `\'s` and other similar methods around the `"[ ]"` with no success.

I know I can just rename the column after giving it any name, such as `"PlaceHolderName"`, but is there a way to do this with one line of code? That function does not accept column name inside
 `" "`, so it feels different compared to something like `Index="[[asdsa][[" ....` where I can type whatever I want inside the `" "`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [dictionary unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/334655/16343464) to pass the name as parameter:

```
DataFrame1.assign(**{'Weight [kg]': [1,2,3,4]})
```