# Transform python dictionary in parameters function, and evaluate in a loop

Tags: python, pydantic

I've a loop and I had a Pydantic model in a list.
But, when I add a field in the table, I have changes this code. But it's not dynamic (the field names are the same that the keys):

```
for t_one in table1:
    for t_two in table2:
        my_list.append(PydanticModel(id=t_one.id, name=t_one.name, version=t_two.version, area=t_two.area, pack=t_two.pack))
```

So, I want, for example, have a list of t_two fields (Ttwo.**table**.columns.keys()).
And a code like this :

```
my_list.append(PydanticModel({k: v for k, v in fields.items()})
```

It's possible ?

UPDATE #1 :
I made the dictionary field like this :

```
fields = {"id":"t_one.id", "name":"t_one.name", "version":"t_two.version", "area":"t_two.area", "pack":"t_two.pack"}
```

When I run the code (I've tried also with eval()), Python doesn't find the fields...

I've the same error in this piece of code (in a class) :

```
def gett(self):
    self.pack = 99
    i = "pack"

    # display "99"
    print(eval(f'self.{i}')) 

    # Error : 
    # return [eval(f'self.{x}') for x in self.all_fields()]
    #         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    # File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    # NameError: name 'self' is not defined

    return [eval(f'self.{x}') for x in self.all_fields()]
```

Thanks
F

Comment: Not sure I completely understand, do you mean something like `PydanticModel(**fields)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a dictionary to a function as keyword parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334655/passing-a-dictionary-to-a-function-as-keyword-parameters)

Comment: `"t_one.id"` you probably mean to write `t_one.id` without the quotes. Similarly for the other arguments.

Comment: the "t_one.id" is generated dynamicly based on the field's names. So it's a string. In the PydanticModel model, I want to pass the variables "without naming" it

Comment: for the UPDATE #1, the eval() function must have this "symbols = {"self": self}" on the second parameter.